# Moving Sign Communication Protocol v1.2 with Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, raspberry-pi

This is my first post here so forgive me if some questions might be out of scope, but basically I'm trying to write my own program to push messages from a Raspberry Pi to a LED scrolling sign via serial communication (USB on Pi -> RS232 adapter -> LED sign).

Im not very familiar with serial communication in general, but am attempting to use the PySerial library on the Pi (http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial.html) in the format of Moving Sign Protocol V1.2 (http://www.brgprecision.com/pdffiles/Protocol12.pdf).

Here is my python code thus far, error free, yet the plugged in sign doesnt receive any data.

```
import serial
#default port is /dev/tty/USB0
#portname, baudrate, timeout
port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
port.open()    port.write('0x00\0x01\"FF"\"03"\0x02\'A'\'A'\'A'\'2'\'2'\'7F'\'0100'\'1200'\'000'\'1'\"OMFG"\0x03\"0564"\0x04')
port.close()
```

Basically, I dont know how to parse the message Im trying to write into proper serial data packages. Do I send the protocol and text message all in one go like above? Or must I parse each of the fields and send them separately like:

```
port.write('01')   # start of head
port.write('46')   # pc address
port.write('46')   # number 1 display

ect...
```

I should mention that I also have sniffed the USB serial communication on my PC and can confirm this serial information is correct, I just have no real idea how to use it on a RPi. Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to use bytes

```
0x00 == 0 == "\x00"
```

which is not the same as `"0x00"` which is really `"\x30\x78\x30\x30"` which is 4 characters not the single byte that you are hoping to achieve

so to send the part A

```
ser.write("\x00"*5) # 5 null bytes
```

to send the SOH part

```
ser.write("\x01")
```

Im not sure what the address stuff is... but that hopefully gives you an idea

Comment: Thank you Joran, because of your insight on byte format (specifically the \x prefix before every bye) I have successfully communicated with my sign. Thanks a lot!